# How to get all the seasons from a list of months in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, algorithm

I'm analyzing a dataset where I have medical bootcamp informations.[image]
From start date and end date(day/month/year) of this bootcamps, I've created a function that lists all the months between startdate and enddate

```
import datetime
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, MONTHLY

def list_months_in_date(start_date: datetime, end_date : datetime) -> list :
    strt_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%d-%b-%y")
    end_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, "%d-%b-%y")
    dates = [dt for dt in rrule(MONTHLY, dtstart=strt_dt, until=end_dt)]
    distinct_months = []
    months = [date.strftime("%B") for date in dates if date.strftime("%B") not in distinct_months]
    distinct_months = list(set(months))

    return distinct_months
```

and I have my function to obtain season from a range of dates

```
def list_months_to_season(distinct_months : list) -> list:
    season = []
    autumn = ["September","October","November"]
    winter = ["December","January","February"]
    summer = ["June","July","August"]
    spring = ["March","April","May"]
    for month in distinct_months:
        if month in autumn :
            season.append("autuumn")
        if month in winter :
            season.append("winter")
        if month in spring :
            season.append("spring")
        if month in summer :
            season.append("summer")
    
    return season
```

What I need is to obtain the seasons between start date and end date (Summer, Spring,Winter, Autumn)
in order to have

```
|id_medicalcamp|start_date|end_date  |seasons      |
|    0010      |01/06/2019|01/09/2020|summer,autumn|
```

I'm running following code

```
df_med_camps['season_label'] = df_med_camps.apply(lambda data : list_months_in_date(data["Camp_Start_Date"],data["Camp_End_Date"]))
```

that gives me error KeyError: 'Camp_Start_Date'

Comment: Use `pd.Series.dt.month` to get the number of month and then `map` to season directly. No need to create custom function.

Comment: maybe I'm understanding what you mean, but how to put the list into column season_label ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First cast your dates to `Datetime`, then create `dict` of season and `map` by month:

```
df["start_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start_date"], format="%d/%m/%Y")
df["end_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["end_date"], format="%d/%m/%Y")

s = {6:"Summer", 7:"Summer", 8:"Summer", 9:"Autumn", 10: "Autumn"} #...

df["label"] = df.filter(like="date").apply(lambda d: d.dt.month.map(s)).agg(", ".join, axis=1)

print (df)

   id_medicalcamp start_date   end_date           label
0              10 2019-06-01 2020-09-01  Summer, Autumn
```

Comment: a little bit of correction for who is looking at this question : correct format for 16-Aug-03 is "%d-%b-%y"

Comment: You didn't provide sample data, so I am using your expected output which is `%m`. For duplicate season, you can use `...agg(lambda d: ",".join(d.unique()), axis=1)`.